# Jar Executable what am I doing wrong?

Tags: java, eclipse, excel, jar, apache-poi

I am using the Eclipse IDE to program. After following a tutorial on Apache POI:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RsrF2Ku7ad4

I created an executable jar through eclipse and the following steps from the following link: http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-37.htm

1. From the menu bar's File menu, select Export.
2. Expand the Java node and select Runnable JAR file. Click Next.
3. In the  Runnable JAR export wizard Runnable JAR File Specification page, I select the WriteExcel launch configuration to use to create a runnable JAR.
4. In the Export destination field, I placed it in my Eclipse workspace.
5. Then I chose package required libraries into generated JAR files.

I then associated JAR files with Java(TM) Platform SE binary in windows.
However when I double click it doesn't create an excel file like it does when i run the program in Eclipse. Running the jar file from the comand line doesnt return an error or create the excel file either.

Clearly I did something wrong any help is greatly appreciated.

edit:
Code Used is the same as the youtube tutorial:

```js
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormat;

public class WriteExcel {
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
  HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
  HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("FirstExcelSheet");
  HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(0);
  HSSFCell cell = row.createCell(0);
  cell.setCellValue("1. Cell");
  
  cell = row.createCell(1);
  DataFormat format = workbook.createDataFormat();
  CellStyle dateStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
  dateStyle.setDataFormat(format.getFormat("dd.mm.yyyy"));
  cell.setCellStyle(dateStyle);
  cell.setCellValue(new Date());
  
  row.createCell(2).setCellValue("3. Cell");
  
  sheet.autoSizeColumn(1);
  
  workbook.write(new FileOutputStream("excel.xls"));
  workbook.close();
 }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you are using completly different version of java from eclipse in your OS ?

Comment: My guess is that your jar is working, but has some coding issues or the file is written to a relative path and you cannot find it. Try adding a simple `System.out.println("hello")`. You should get see "hello" if you execute the jar on the command line. Then make sure you use an absolute path to write your file to.

Comment: @Sercan Ozdemir: That would trigger an error message or stack trace on the command line.

Comment: How do you run the Jar from command line? What `Exception` handling do you have inside your code?

Comment: @Sercam Ozdemir: I am using the same java version.

Comment: @BetaRide I should of thought about adding a simple print out will test asap.

Comment: @SubOptimal I ran the jar from comand line with: 

java -jar "C:....jar"

Comment: @Evulafro Ok. And what `Exception` handling do you have implemented? Maybe you suppress all exceptions. Without having a look at your code everthing we can do is guessing.

Comment: @SubOptimal my code is exactly the same as the one in the tutorial video. I believe the only exception is throw Ioexception. I cant access youtube as im currently at work

Comment: @SubOptimal Code has been edited into the question

Comment: @Evulafro Please have a look to my answer and compare the steps with yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a small code fix

from

```
workbook.write(new FileOutputStream("excel.xls"));
workbook.close();
```

to

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("excel.xls");
workbook.write(fos);
fos.close();
```

and executing the steps you mention to generate the Jar file. I get a Jar file with following content (result of `jar tf WriteExcel.jar`)

```
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
org/
org/eclipse/
org/eclipse/jdt/
org/eclipse/jdt/internal/
org/eclipse/jdt/internal/jarinjarloader/
org/eclipse/jdt/internal/jarinjarloader/JIJConstants.class
org/eclipse/jdt/internal/jarinjarloader/JarRsrcLoaderManifestInfo.class
org/eclipse/jdt/internal/jarinjarloader/JarRsrcLoader.class
org/eclipse/jdt/internal/jarinjarloader/RsrcURLConnection.class
org/eclipse/jdt/internal/jarinjarloader/RsrcURLStreamHandler.class
org/eclipse/jdt/internal/jarinjarloader/RsrcURLStreamHandlerFactory.class
WriteExcel.class
XLStoCSVConvert.class
org/apache/
org/apache/poi/
org/apache/poi/ss/
org/apache/poi/ss/examples/
org/apache/poi/ss/examples/UpdateWorkBook.class
org/apache/poi/ss/examples/ToCSVExcelFilenameFilter.class
org/apache/poi/ss/examples/ToCSV.class
org/apache/poi/ss/examples/CreateNewWorkBook.class
poi-ooxml-3.10.1.jar
poi-ooxml-schemas-3.10.1.jar
xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar
stax-api-1.0.1.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar
poi-3.10.1.jar
commons-codec-1.5.jar
```

content of the file `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Rsrc-Class-Path: ./ poi-ooxml-3.10.1.jar poi-ooxml-schemas-3.10.1.jar
 xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar stax-api-1.0.1.jar dom4j-1.6.1.jar xml-apis-1.0.b2
 .jar poi-3.10.1.jar commons-codec-1.5.jar
Class-Path: .
Rsrc-Main-Class: WriteExcel
Main-Class: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader
```

Executing the Jar with `java -jar WriteExcel.jar` generates the file `excel.xls`.

**edit run with double-click**
If it's not executed when you do a double-click on the Jar file in the Windows Explorer the main reasons could be

- the Jar file was compiled with a newer JDK version then the JRE which is assigned to execute Jar files (check with `java -version` on both PCs)
- a wrong application has been assigned to execute the Jar file
  check in the registry the value of key `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\jarfile\shell\open\command` it must be similar to `"C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_66\bin\javaw.exe" -jar "%1" %*` (the path depends on the installed version)

Comment: Thank you so much this now works with:   

java -jar WriteExcel.jar


However, double clicking the jar file still does not work. Is there something I'm doing wrong? I really need it to be a double click situation before programming further. 


Im creating this for a friend who wouldnt ever run a cmd.

Comment: @Evulafro Have a look in my updated answer for a solution with the double click on the Jar file.

Comment: thank you for your continued support. The pc im compiling the program with is the same as the one attempting to open it, since im still just testing it out.
As for the second option the registry is correct: http://i.imgur.com/E7kHZqT.png

Comment: Just noticed yours is 66 gonna update and see if it fixes issue though i have my doubts xD

Comment: Weirdest thing ever it fixed the issue. not sure how. but now that its 66 it works lol thank you soooooo much :)

Comment: @Evulafro Glad to hear that it's now working for you. Maybe something additional to the mentioned registry setting was broken, which got corrected with installing the update.