# Generating Excel file from JAR executable

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am facing an issue to generate Excel file from a runnable JAR.

I am able to create an Excel file from Eclipse. I have created a runnable JAR file of the same Java class. But when I execute the same class from a JAR, as soon as `XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();` line appears, Java skips the rest of the code and comes back to the class from where it called.

The weird thing is no exception is thrown.

As per [Jar Executable what am I doing wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33887003/jar-executable-what-am-i-doing-wrong?rq=1) post, I have already verified my registry which is same as the Eclipse environment.

Comment: Are the apache-poi-jars in your runnable jar included?

Comment: "The weird thing is no exception is thrown.": How are you starting the runnable jar? By double clicking it? Then where do you expect the exception's stacktraces shall be printed to? Try running it in console using `java -jar yourprogram.jar`. Always not any exceptions?

Comment: Yes. All the required jars are in bin folder inside runnable jar. - @Ralf

Comment: I have tried running it from console. Issue is same. No error/exception thrown. @ Axel

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem. I made a class that creates a workbook and saves it (as seen in http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#NewWorkbook). I added commons-collections4-4.1.jar, poi-3.17.jar, poi-ooxml-3.17.jar, poi-ooxml-schemas-3.17.jar and xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar. Then I exported it as runnable jar and it works.

Comment: @Ralf Renz: It works having a Manifest containing Class-Path entries pointing to the other jars in filesystem. But not having "All the required jars in bin folder inside runnable jar." as the OP stated. For this - having a jar containing other jars - additional software is needed which provides custom classloader that knows how to load classes and resources from a jars inside an archive, instead of from jars in the filesystem.

Comment: I used the Eclipse Export as Runnable Jar. That deals with all that stuff.

Comment: I have all the dependent jars in bin. But my Manifest is only pointing to my main class. It does not include path to other jars.. Will that be an issue?

Comment: I was using Eclipse Export as Jar. I tried Eclipse Export as Runnable Jar and that worked.. Eclipse Export as Runnable Jar has appended all dependent jars with main class in Manifest. I think that solved my issue...

Comment: Thank you to both of you for the help.. Really appreciate your quick response..